# Programatically trigger dhtmlx header column click

Tags: dhtmlx

I have integrated DHTMLX grid and want to programatically call click event on a column header. I have tried **onHeaderClick** but that did not help.

Can anyone please guide me, Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem cannot be reproduced locally. onHeader event works well: http://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxgrid_onheaderclick_event.html

Comment: Hi Paul, I dont want to attach the event, i want to trigger it. i.e. i want to trigger header column click event.

Comment: It's a little hard since the grid is generated entirely via html, a simple yet not so efficient solution using jquery selectors would be something like:
$('div[class="hdrcell"]:nth(0)').trigger('click') where the :nth(0), is the index of the column you wish to trigger the click on

Comment: Just trigger the code (function) you trigger when you trigger it? If you know what I mean? :-) Or don't I know what I'm talking about? :-D